# Process text in emacs

Tags: emacs

I need to define a function that reads all the content of a specific document in Emacs and processes the text in it. For example, I'm reading an XML file and I want to search for specific attributes and count the number of occurrences. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`M-x count-matches RET`

You may use regex to match your attribute

I added this small animation out of screenshots to show you an example of usage.
If you need a more complex one, feel free to ask.

[image: Small example of usage]

If you want to solve this with Emacs-Lisp, 
check out -> [question]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522/tips-for-learning-elisp/1313997#1313997 espacially the point `count-string-matches`, or do it like this:

`(defun count-words ()

  (interactive)

  (let ((words (count-matches "[-A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9.]*"

                              (point-min) (point-max))))

    (message (format "%d matches" words))))`

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how I can use the search function of emacs in my own code? just a very basic example will suffice.

Comment: @Arash i added a small gif'ed screencast ;)

Comment: Man you are awesome :-D. I understood that from your explanation though but I really appreciate the time you spent on it. However do you know how can I call this method from some code that I am writing. I am writing a major mode and that's how I need to use it. cheers.

Comment: @Arash You are welcome =), check out my last edit right underneath the animated Gif